# I get error when I use class named "String" in my program.Is it naming Conflict?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and was trying to find out different naming conflict scenario.
This program is giving me error mentioned below.

```
class String {
    int a=3;       
}

class StringBuffer {
   int  c=5;
}

public class Test1 {
    int b=6;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test1 obj = new Test1();
        String obj2 =new String();
        StringBuffer obj3 = new StringBuffer();
        System.out.println(obj.b);
        //System.out.println(obj2.a);
        System.out.println(obj3.c);
     }

}
```

> Error: Main method not found in class `Test1`, please define the main method >as:
>    public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

I have searched for this error thread but couldn't figure out why I am getting this error. When I comment out that String class then my program works fine and gives me output. I am newbie, so please can someone be kind enough to tell me if this is really naming conflict or what is wrong in this program.

I know it is bad idea create class with such names but as newbie I was doing this Just to understand the naming conflicts . I couldn't understand why String class is giving error but not StringBuffer.

Comment: Might I ask what the Point of your String and StringBuffer classes is? Unless you specifically wanted to test if you can name your custom classes like already existing ones they don't seem to have much purpose and little to do with their names.

Comment: No - String isn't a reserve keyword. @CHIVID is hiding java.lang.String with his own implementation. When you do this, you need to fully qualify java.lang.String

Comment: Don't use standard Java API type names for custom types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom `String` class hides `java.lang.String`, so in

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

the compiler uses your custom `String` class, and therefore doesn't find a `main` method that takes a `java.lang.String[]` argument.

You could change it to

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)
```

But it would make more sense not to define your own `String` class.

Comment: Thanks !! This clarified by doubt of why String Buffer was not giving error

Answer (score 1):

It is bad an idea to create classes with the same names as in JDK. By default classes from java.lang.* are included in the class path. The simplest solution for you is to rename String and StringBuffer classes.

Comment: Yes!! I was Just doing this to figure out different naming conflicts practically as I am java learner.Sure I will keep this in mind in future.